# using usort to find lowest in series => multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to use usort to find the lowest 'price' in return data.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
        return strcmp($a[0]["price"], $b[0]["price"]);
}
usort($openorders, "cmp");
var_dump($openorders);
```

output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(7) {
      ["order_id"]=>
      string(8) "43410734"
      ["price"]=>
      string(9) "0.0035347"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(7) {
      ["order_id"]=>
      string(8) "43410610"
      ["price"]=>
      string(9) "0.0032347"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(7) {
      ["order_id"]=>
      string(8) "43410581"
      ["price"]=>
      string(9) "0.0033347"
    }
  }
}
```

I appear to not even access the data with [0] or without, in my function.

How do I return the lowest price in a multidimentional array using usort or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
<?php

$openorders= array(
  '0'=>
  array(
    '0'=>array(
      "order_id"=>"43410734",
      "price"=>"0.0035347"
    ),
    '1'=>array(
      "order_id"=>"43410610",
      "price"=>"0.0032347"
    ),
    '2'=>array(
      "order_id"=>"43410581",
      "price"=>"0.0033347"
    )
  )
); // original array

echo "<pre/>";print_r($openorders); // print original array

$new_openorders = $openorders[0]; // since original array have one extra level so assign it's inner array to a new variable

function sortByOrder($a, $b) { // callback function
    return strcmp($a["price"], $b["price"]);
}

usort($new_openorders, 'sortByOrder'); 

echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_openorders); // print the new array
```

Output:-https://eval.in/599410

Now again you can easily do:-

```
$openorders[0] = $new_openorders; // to get back original array
```

Also directly without using any new array variable you can do it like this also:-

https://eval.in/599411

Comment: I couldn't figure out why mine was not sorting, and then I looked at your output and noticed yours did not sort by price either  :(

Comment: @dooode  my both links have correct output (price in ascending order). look to the second array in each link

Comment: I got it. the actual return data had LTC_BTC and not [0]

Comment: @dooode  great to hear that you get your solution. cheers:):):)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $d1 = $a[0]['price'];
    $d2 = $b[0]['price'];

    if ($d1 == $d2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($d1 < $d2) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($openorders[0], "cmp");
var_dump($openorders);
```

Comment: I tried to call on the function the same as the post, and also tried using ->  $oorders = cmp($openorders);  and still blew errors.  the variable $openorders contains my data.

Comment: with the element [0], I blow errors https://bpaste.net/show/24d7995e956a  and still no sort. if I remove the element, error goes away, but still no sort